# Customer credit account

Tags: invoice, application

pretty new to magento 2, but Is it possible to set up a credit account in magento 2?

So a customer can purchase items (up to a limit) and then get invoiced at the end of the month.

Another option might be that the customer can pay with a P.O. (as a payment method) but how would this be set up so only approved customers can pay that way?

And then how would the customers apply for a credit account?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: it is not possible with default you heve to find some extencion

Comment: Magento natively does not have this feature, either you develop it and you have a lot of things to do (it's a good exercise), or you have to find an extension that does this feature as the previous comment said.